# Oracle SQL Regexp_replace matching

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, replace, matching

Here is a funky matching that I need to accomplish.

`A5.1.9.11.2`

Needs to become:

`A05.01.09.11.02`

The amount of DOT sections will vary from none to many.  And the letter "A" will always be there and always be 1 character.

I would like to use the regexp_replace() function in order to use this as a sorting mechanism.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle SQL doesn't support lookaround assertions, which would be useful for this case:

```
s/([0-9](?<![0-9]))/0\1/g
```

You'll have to use at least two replacements:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '([0-9]+)', '0\1'), '0([0-9]{2})', '\1')
```

Comment: +1 I got stranded on the lookaround problem.  Using two REGEXP_REPLACE() calls, is not intuitive but it does work.